# SAS - Chi squared independence test for multiple variables

Tags: sas

I need to perform Chi squared independence test on binary variable (v1) against multiple categorical ones (more than 200, v2-v20..) excluding id column. The aim is to obtain a sorted list of chi statistics that will show which variables are most correlated with v1 variable. Could you help me to write this simple SAS code?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please provide a [mcve] and review the [ask] section.

Comment: This is inefficient but it works and produces a clean table. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/b308ac2cfc9b4db0ee3d793567627af0